# При разворачивании-сворачивании QVideoWidget срывает с окна приложения в угол монитора

Tags: c++, linux, qt5

Имеется программа, в окне которой находится виджет `QVideoWidget` (включен в `layout`). В этот виджет установлен `eventFilter` который сворачивает/разворачивает его на полный экран по двойному клику мышки:

```
bool mywidget::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {
    QVideoWidget * v = reinterpret_cast<QVideoWidget*>(watched);
    if(v->isFullScreen()) v->setFullScreen(false);
    else v->setFullScreen(true);
}
return false;
}
```

. Но возникла такая проблема: после сворачиванию `QVideoWidget` оказывается в углу монитора как отдельный виджет (его, например можно закрыть нажав на кнопку), а в консоли высвечивается:

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
```

При этом проблема не возникает под виндоусом... Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: А если вручную создать окно с QVideoWidget и захаркодено выполнить: `v.show();` `v->setFullScreen(true)` `v->setFullScreen(false)`? Кст, тот код с if'ами можно сократить до: `v->setFullScreen(!v->isFullScreen());`

Comment: @gil9red если сделать так, как вы предлагали, то все впорядку - окно `QVideoWidget` по прежнему в окне программы и правильно расположен.

Comment: @gil9red не могу понять почему так? Это из-за фильтра? Или из-за событий мыши? Почему под виндоус нет этой проблемы?

Comment: Судя по всему это баг. Пока прогресса нет: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53671

Comment: @Fat-Zer ага, вот оно как... Спасибо. Если оформите как ответ - приму

Comment: почитал поподробнее: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28168 проблема вроде в QGLWidget и ее пофиксили в версии 10.6 (у меня 10.1)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, версии чего?

Comment: @Fat-Zer qt-5, если я все правильно понял

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch. нет QTBUG-28168 пофиксили до Qt-5.3 и он относился к MacOS-10.6... По поводу ответа — я воздержусь, пока не буду уверен что это действительно баг и тот самый — уж очень он пока что мало внимания получил...

Comment: можно попробовать при переходе обратно заново пересобрать и установить layout главного виджета.